# Observable for Absolute Overall Magnetization of an Ising Model

Tags: measurement, density-matrix, ising-model

I am currently following [this](https://juliaphysics.github.io/PhysicsTutorials.jl/tutorials/general/quantum_ising/quantum_ising.html) tutorial for generating a phase transition plot that has been generated in the same tutorial. In this tutorial's `magnetization` function, they take the sum after taking the `abs` of each term. I do not understand the motivation behind taking the absolute. This function does not seem to match the observable that has been described in the latex formula.

I have been trying to replicate this plot using a quantum algorithm, but I am only able to generate this if I calculate $\text{tr}[\text{abs}(O \rho)]$ rather than the traditional approach of $\text{tr}[O\rho]$. How do I construct $O'$ such that $\text{tr}[O'\rho] = \text{tr}[\text{abs}(O \rho)]$?